# Merging two columns into one separate column

Tags: sql, database, hive

I am trying to merge two columns in hive in a new column such that all the rows under one column appear down to other.

For example, this is my table:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|maths1       |    maths2  |   physics1  |  physics2 |    
+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|       10    | 20         | 30          |  40       |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
+-------------+------------+
|maths        |    physics |
+-------------+------------+
|       10    |     30     |
+--------------------------+
|       20    |     40     |
+--------------------------+
```

I want a query for this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how many columns, do you have like "maths1, maths2, physics1, physics2" become 4, then ???? and how data contains your table in form of rows? Does performance matter?

Comment: @Vivek,Is there any short way for that?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your size of data and number of column that need to be transform, as I asked in previous comment

Comment: Actually my real question is somewhat different,So should i ask it seperately or edit in this question only?

Comment: Question is already answered so, I think you can you ask another or I don't know, you can refer the link for more about "Asking a question"  :   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to unpivot the data.

try this:

```
SELECT maths1 maths, physics1 physics
FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT maths2 maths, physics3 physics
FROM tableName
```

Assuming you have another column `student_id`, query will look like this:

```
SELECT student_id, maths1 maths, physics1 physics
FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT student_id, maths2 maths, physics3 physics
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select maths1 as maths, physics1 as physics from table
union 
select maths2 as maths, physics2 as physics from table
```